# Foreach syntax on smarty 1.6

Tags: foreach, smarty, facebook-group

I use Smarty v.1.6, 
in php :

```
$groups = $user_groups['data'];
```

`$user_groups['data']` derived from `$user_groups = $facebook->api('/'.$fbuser.'/groups');`
(I retrieve user facebook group data and it returns an array). Then I assign `$groups` in tpl file :

> $template->assign("userGroupsData", $groups);

**I want to print only the name of each group**, so in tpl :

```
{foreach from=$userGroupsData item=member}
  {$member->name}
{/foreach}
```

but the result shows nothing. `{$member->name|@print_r}` will produce :

`11111111111` (as the number of my group)

What's wrong with my code? Please help..

Here is the array result of `{$member|print_r}` :

```
Array ( 
    [name] => beasiswa dirmawa ugm 
    [unread] => 25 
    [bookmark_order] => 999999999 
    [id] => 148164981898119 ) 1 
Array ( 
    [name] => Diskusi Jurusan IKE 
    [unread] => 1 
    [bookmark_order] => 999999999 
    [id] => 131266600402713 ) 1 
Array ( 
    [name] => ILMU KOMPUTER - UGM 
    [unread] => 7 
    [bookmark_order] => 9 
    [id] => 392009304179631 ) 1 
Array ( 
    [name] => Facebook Developers 
    [unread] => 25 
    [bookmark_order] => 999999999 
    [id] => 146797922030397 ) 1 

...etc
```

Any help would greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's an array you should use the period symbol (in smarty 2 and up, at least):

{$member.name}

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl#language.variables.assoc.arrays

but it may be different in the version you're using